# How to add innerHTML to tooltip tiitle using typescript in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, kendo-ui, tooltip, innerhtml

I am trying to render html inside tooltip element title attribute. But for some reason the html content is not rendering as text instead of HTML as it is.

Below is my Structure to my Angular project:

library.comp.html  : Where my component code exists
library.comp.ts : Where my comp TS code exists

demo.comp.html : Where i fetch my comp from library
demo.comp.ts : where i maniplulate comp contents and render the same in demo.comp.html

Below is the code of my angular project :

**library.comp.html**

```
   kendoTooltip
   [id]="tooltipConfig.id!"
   [tooltipTemplate]="tooltipConfig.tooltipTemplate!"
   [title]="tooltipConfig.title!"
   [innerHTML]="tooltipConfig.text!"
   [closable]="tooltipConfig.closable!"
   [position]="tooltipConfig.position!"
   [tooltipWidth]="tooltipConfig.tooltipWidth!"
   [showOn]="tooltipConfig.showOn!"
  ></div>
```

**library.comp.ts**

```
export class AuraTooltipComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() tooltipConfig!: TooltipConfig;
```

**demo.comp.html**

`<aura-tooltip  [tooltipConfig]="tooltipConfig_basic"></aura-tooltip>`

**demo.comp.ts**

```
this.tooltipConfig_basic = {
      title: "<h1>Click</h1> the button to show the tooltip with",
      text: 'Tooltip1',
      closable: true,
      position: 'right',
      tooltipWidth: 400,
      id:'tooltip2'

    }
```

**Output : **

Current Output

[image]

**Expected Output : **

Need the Tag to be rendered instead of text inside tooltip title content.

As shown above, i wasn't able to render the HTML to the component library and back to the demo.html.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is that even possible? It looks like kendo-ui saves the title in an attribute for the element and then I think it retrieves it and displays it. I don't think that is possible https://github.com/telerik/kendo-ui-core/blob/master/src/kendo.tooltip.js

Comment: I've never worked with kendo, but from the docs I would guess, you will have to add any HTML content in the `template`. See https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jndutv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

What you're interested in is the Kendo Popover, which is "a popup with rich content that is related to a single or multiple UI elements", as it says in the documents.
It has special directives for it:

- kendoPopoverTitleTemplate
- kendoPopoverBodyTemplate
- kendoPopoverActionsTemplate

You use it like this (demo from documentation):

```
<button
  kendoPopoverAnchor
  [popover]="myPopover"
  kendoButton
  themeColor="primary"
  [style.marginLeft.px]="200"
>
  Show Waffles Recipe
</button>

<kendo-popover #myPopover [width]="300" position="bottom">
  <ng-template kendoPopoverTitleTemplate>
    <div class="popover-title">Pumpkin Waffles</div>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template kendoPopoverBodyTemplate>
    <img class="picture" [src]="wafflesImg" />
    <div>{{ wafflesRecipe }}</div>
  </ng-template>

  <ng-template kendoPopoverActionsTemplate>
    <button kendoButton fillMode="flat" themeColor="primary">
      <span class="k-icon k-i-heart-outline"></span>
      Like
    </button>
  </ng-template>
</kendo-popover>
```

And the result looks like this:
[image: Screenshot from demo]

You can read further about the Kendo Popover [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/tooltips/api/PopoverTitleTemplateDirective/) and specifically about templates [here](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/tooltips/popover/templates/).

Comment: Any idea how one could use kendo popover to override the kendo tooltip for kendo chart items? Couldn't find anything related to that.

Comment: The Kendo Chart  tooltip uses Angular templates for defining the tooltip content, for instance using the kendoChartSeriesTooltipTemplate directive so you can show whatever HTML you want there. There's no need to use the Kendo Popover. Do you have a specific problem with the chart tooltip?
@ShuaibKunji

Comment: I need to display a list(a long scrollable one) with some action buttons in the tooltip which is not possible with the kendo-chart-series-item-tooltip.

Comment: I also need it to be displayed on click instead of on hover and stay there even after the cursor is moved.

Comment: I think that programmatic control might help me achieve what I need to do: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/tooltips/popover/programmatic-control/